# Vimscript: Filetypes aren't being loaded

Tags: vim, cygwin

I'm unfamiliar with vimscript and learning how it works.  I want to install this into my configuration: https://github.com/vim-scripts/Twee-Integration-for-Vim  I put this directly into my `.vim` directory (that may be where I went wrong).

It has a `~/.vim/ftdetect/twee.vim` file and I made some modifications to it.  It looks like this:

```
" markdown filetype file
if exists("did\_load\_filetypes")
        echom "I put this here"
        finish
endif

augroup twee
        au! BufRead,BufNewFile *.twee,*.tw   setfiletype twee
        autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.twee,*.tw    compiler twee
augroup END
```

I added that echom myself.  Whenever I open a file with a .twee extension, it prints out that echom.  But when the file is opened, if I typed `:set filetype?` it prints this out: `filetype=`

What am I doing wrong?  How do I get it to run this autogroup?  BTW, if I do `:set filetype=twee` in the local buffer, the syntax highlighting works correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The answer was here: http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/FTDetect-td1151042.html

There are a number of different methods of doing filetype detection;
you have confused two of them.

I don't understand exactly how the `ftdetect` directory works, but
`:help ftdetect` says that if you are going to add filetype
detection for a new file type by putting a file in the 'ftdetect'
directory, that file should contain *only* the autocommand, e.g.,

```
    au BufRead,BufNewFile *.wibble set filetype=wibblewobble
```

Note that there is no `!` after the `au` and the command is 
`set filetype`, not `setfiletype.  Note also that the help entry says:

```
...there is no "augroup" command, this has already been
done when sourcing your file.
```

If, on the other hand, you add filetype detection by creating your
own `~/.vim/filetype.vim` file, *then* you would put in that file the
commands you used above, i.e.,

```
    if exists("did_load_filetypes")
      finish
    endif
    augroup filetypedetect
      au! BufRead,BufNewFile *.wibble setfiletype wibblewobble
    augroup END
```